# What's the probability that $X_i = \max\{ X_1, \dots, X_N \}$, for independent normal random variables $X_1, \dots, X_N$ with a common mean of $0$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, optimization, random-variables

Suppose we have $N$ independent normally distributed random variables, $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_N$, all of which have a mean of zero but whose variances, $\sigma^2_1, \sigma_2^2, \dots, \sigma_n^2$, may differ.

I'm interested in the probability that any one of these variables takes on the maximum value $\max\{ X_1, X_2, \dots, X_N\}$.  For instance, what is the probability that $X_1 = \max\{ X_1, X_2, \dots, X_N\}$?

I believe this is going to depend upon the variances $\sigma_i^2$, but I'm having trouble seeing how to calculate the probability from the variances.

---

Think of it like this: race horses $1$ through $N$ have their speeds drawn from independent normally distributed distributions with common mean $0$, but the variance of the distribution horse $i$ is drawing from may differ from the variance of the distribution horse $j$ is drawing from.

Whichever race horse is furthest ahead after 1 minute wins, so whichever race horse draws the greatest speed will be the winner.

What is the probability that horse 1 wins the race?

Comment: If they have different variances, they cannot be i.i.d. So are they just independent or is there more information known about the distribution of these random variables?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I meant to say that each $X_i$ is independently distributed. I've edited the question.

I'm interested in the general case where we only know that they're independent and symmetrically distributed around 0, but I'd also like to know if there are results for specific cases, e.g., if each Xi is normal.

Comment: For continuous random variables with identical distributions, the probability is $1/N.$ But for discontinuous or discrete random variables, it really depends, and if they aren't identical distributions it is very hard to say.

Comment: "but I'm having trouble seeing how to calculate the p.m.f. from the variances" --- There's a class of distributions which are recoverable from the means and [co]variances but it's not all of them, so in general this is impossible.

Comment: I've updated the question so that it is just asking about normally distributed random variables.

Comment: If $Y=\max\{X_1, X_2, ... X_N\}$, then we have $P(Y\leq y)=F_Y(y)=F_{X_1}(y)\cdot F_{X_2}(y)\cdot \ldots \cdot F_{X_n}(y)$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1388407 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2115048 are related (but not full answers)

Comment: @callculus42: I know how to calculate the density for $Y = \max\{X_1, ..., X_N \}$. My question is different. I'm interested in the probability that $X_1 = \max\{ X_1, \dots X_N\}$

Comment: @user999003 At the first glance the question doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: the most straightforward idea is to apply the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) by conditioning on the value of $X_{i_0}$, which will yield an integral involving the product of the CDF of each $X_i$ for $i\ne i_0$, but I don't think it will yield a closed-form expression.

Comment: @callculus42 I've updated the question with an intuitive explanation which will hopefully help explain the question I'm asking.

Comment: I know it's not your intended purpose, but I got a laugh out of half the horses running backwards, so thanks for that! ;-) (re-interpreting "speed" as "velocity", of course, but I think this is necessary for your illustration to match)

Comment: Try N=2. The problem boils down to finding $P(X_1 > X_2)$, i.e. $P(X_1-X_2>0)$. Since $X_1, X_2$ are independent and ZM Gaussian, $X_1-X_2$ is ZM Gaussian with variance $\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2$.So the probability is 0.5. Does this generalize?

Comment: N=2 is a special case. It doesn't generalize